# how i can record desktop audio and microphone audio using javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, desktop, mediarecorder, voice-recording

i have to  a record audio for both desktop audio and micophone

currently i am using media recorder

```
const recFunction = async() => {
    try {
        const mediaDevices = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(typeOfMedia)
        if (mediaDevices.active === true) {
            recStream = new MediaRecorder(mediaDevices, options);
            recStream.ondataavailable = e => {
                chunks.push(e.data);
                if (recStream.state == 'inactive') {
                    let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                    $('#hiddenAudio').val(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                    $('#sendButton').trigger("click");  
                    document.getElementById("recordData").classList.remove("recordBoxHide")
                    // createAudioElement(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
                }
            }
            recStream.onstop = () => {
                chunks = []
            }
            recStream.start()
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
    }
}
```

but problem is that when I am recording desktop audio not recording while connecting earphones and if I disconnect earphones and recording again then desktop audio is recording successful >> that is my main problem
please help me if any one has solution for this problem
suggest to me some library or API  if available in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use recordrtc for audio and video recording

```
import RecordRTC, { StereoAudioRecorder } from 'recordrtc';
const startRecording = async (remote, setChunckCount, chunckCount, userCallSid) => {
    const ac = new AudioContext();
    let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: {
            mandatory: {
                echoCancellation: false,
                googAutoGainControl: false,
                googNoiseSuppression: false,
                googHighpassFilter: false
            }
        }
    });
    let audioTracks = []
    audioTracks.push(stream.getAudioTracks()[0])
    audioTracks.push(remote.getAudioTracks()[0])
    const sources = audioTracks.map(t => ac.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([t])));
    const dest = ac.createMediaStreamDestination();
    sources.forEach(s => s.connect(dest));
    let recorder = new RecordRTC(dest.stream, {
        type: 'audio',
        mimeType: 'audio/wav',
        recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
        numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
        disableLogs: process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === 'development' ? false : true,
        bufferSize: 16384,
        timeSlice: 4000,
        ondataavailable: (blob) => {
            saveRecordingChunck(blob, userCallSid, chunckCount, setChunckCount)
        },
    })
    recorder.startRecording();
    return recorder
}
```

`